# Value of optional type 'Date?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? In Swift 4 XCode 9

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, option-type, uidatepicker

How to unwrap date for Entity
[image: date unwrap img]
Where 
`@IBOutlet weak var dob: UIDatePicker!`

`var selectedEntity: TestEntity!`

[image: TestEntity Structure]

I have following ways no one worked

`self.dob.date = self.selectedEntity?.dob!` // Error Compile Time

`self.dob.date = self.selectedEntity?.dob as! Date` // Waring is coming and if date is nil then runtime crash

Comment: You can unwrap your `self.selectedEntity` like the other posters have already answered OR, if it's critical that your `self.dob.date` has a value, and you want to handle this inline, you could use the nil coalescing operator `??` and provide a fallback value. 

`self.dob.date = self.selectedEntity?.dob ?? Date()` This is effectively saying, if `self.selectedEntity?.dob` is not nil, then use that, otherwise, use `Date()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.selectedEntity?` is an optional. All of it's values are also optional. See [Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) in the Swift documentation for more information. You need to unwrap your optionals before using them as non-optional objects. That's what you are doing when you use the `!` symbol here `self.selectedEntity?.dob!`. That force unwraps the optional and if it is nil, your app will crash. Your `self.dob.date` object is not an optional so you have to unwrap your optional `self.selectedEntity?.dob` object before using it. You can safely unwrap your `self.selectedEntity` object with something like this.

```
if let selectedEntity = selectedEntity {
   self.dob.date = selectedEntity.dob
}
```

Comment: His code won't compile when he tries `self.selectedEntity?.dob!` because that would be trying to force unwrap a non optional property of TestEntity. If he wanted to force unwrap and have his code compile, he'd need to do `self.selectedEntity!.dob`.

Comment: if let selectedEntity = self.selectedEntity{
            self.name.text = selectedEntity.name
            self.dob.date = selectedEntity.dob // Value of optional type 'Date?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
            self.textData.text = self.selectedEntity?.textData
        }

Answer (score 1):

Safely unwrap `selectedEntity`.

```
if let selectedEntity = self.selectedEntity {
    self.name.text = selectedEntity.name
    self.dob.date = selectedEntity.date
}
```

Whenever Xcode suggests the use `!`, don't do it. It's the worst feature of Xcode.

Comment: Fortunately, these suggestions improved in Xcode 10.